# Performing background tasking using Job Scheduler at exact time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

I am working on News app. And I needed to get latest news once a day. For this I used Jobsheduler.Here is the code :

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, JobService.class);
        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(123, componentName)
                .setRequiresCharging(false)
                .setPeriodic(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .build();
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        int resultCode = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);

        if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS){
            Log.d(TAG, "Job Scheduled");
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Job Scheduling failed");
        }
```

But now I need to do this work once in the morning after 6:00 when there will be internet connection.
Is there a way to do this with Job Scheduler. I know that I can do this using Alarm Manager but Job Scheduler is far more better than Alarm Manager in conditions like if there is connection, if device  charging. Or can I achieve this using Workmanager which uses Job Scheduler and AlarmManager if it needs to. Or is there another way of doing this??? Any suggestions are apprecieated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcast receiver along with Work Manager which let you know the connection is available and complete your scheduled task **OR** you can trigger Worker for every 15 minutes after 6:00 AM(Minimum time for 2 consecutive workers) and check if internet is available and do your work

Comment: can i use alarm manager to start the job scheduler every morning at 6:00?

Comment: Alarm manager wont work properly on Android 6+ devices due to more drain of battery, so you have to use broadcast receiver + Job scheduler somewhat like below answer, where you can do like above answer

Comment: Yes you can use and start process like this  AlarmReceiver.setAlarm(true); /* true will force the broadcast */

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "com.test.intent.action.ALARM";
public static Context ctx = OfferlyApplication.getContext();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    /* enqueue the job */
    AlarmJobIntentService.enqueueWork(context, intent);
}
public static void cancelAlarm() {
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    /* cancel any pending alarm */
    alarm.cancel(getPendingIntent());
}
public static void setAlarm(boolean force) {
    cancelAlarm();
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // EVERY X MINUTES
    long delay = (1000 * 60 * 60);
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (!force) {
        when += delay;
    }
    /* fire the broadcast */
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = getPendingIntent();
    int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, pendingIntent);
    else if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, pendingIntent);
    else {
        Log.d("JOB_SCHEDULING","waking device");
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, pendingIntent);
    }
}
private static PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
    //Context ctx;   /* get the application context */
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}
```

**or using work manager for periodic workers**

```
 Constraints myConstraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
            .setRequiresStorageNotLow(true)
            .build();

    PeriodicWorkRequest saveRequest =
            new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker.class, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .setConstraints(myConstraints)
                    .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance()
            .enqueue(saveRequest);
```

Comment: here in work manager example how can I set exact time??? is this possible?